# Passing page number argument in formData is not returning the expected response in scrapy spider , scrapy shell or in postman

Tags: python, python-3.x, pagination, scrapy, web-crawler

I have written a spider that also needs to follow pagination links, however, when I pass the form data with the page number(whatever page number I pass) I am only getting the first page. I have also tried passing all the form data and Request Headers in Postman, with no success.
I would just like to know how to get the specified page number after that looping through multiple pages would not be a problem.

Also for testing purposes I have tried to include and exclude different parameters while sending the request in postman and scrapy.

```py
def start_requests(self):
        url="http://www.1ropani.com/House.aspx"
        payload={"ContentPlaceHolder1_HouseListControl1_GridView1":"Page$2",
        "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HouseListControl1$ItemsPerPageDropDownList":"100",
        "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":"BBBC20B8",
        "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HouseListControl1$BuyRentDropDownList":"On Sale only",
        "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HouseListControl1$PriceRangeDropDownList":"Any Price",
        "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HouseListControl1$LandareaDropDownList":"Any Area",
        "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HouseListControl1$ItemsPerPageDropDownList":"100",
        "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HouseListControl1$SortByDropDownList: Date":"Newest on top",
        "__ASYNCPOST":"true"
        }

        # payload={
        # "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HouseListControl1$ItemsPerPageDropDownList":"100",
        # "__EVENTARGUMENT":"Page$5"}
        # head={"referer":"http://www.1ropani.com/Search.aspx?tt=buy&",
        # "Cookie":"__utma=202999825.102474612.1543209861.1543209861.1543209861.1; __utmz=202999825.1543209861.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); realtabs=0; ASP.NET_SessionId=5zz5gbs2exlm3n1bcvrrhbup; undefined=25",
        # "Host":"www.1ropani.com",
        # "Accept":"*/*",
        # "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",
        # "Cache-Control":"no-cache",
        # "Connection":"keep-alive",
        # # "Content-Length":"3882",
        # "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        # "Origin":"http://www.1ropani.com",
        # "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36",
        # "X-MicrosoftAjax":"Delta=true",
        # "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"}
        head={"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
        "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",
        "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9,ne;q=0.8",
        "Connection":"keep-alive",
        #"Cookie":"__utma=202999825.102474612.1543209861.1543209861.1543209861.1; __utmz=202999825.1543209861.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); realtabs=0; ASP.NET_SessionId=5zz5gbs2exlm3n1bcvrrhbup; RecentlyViewed=7511,7496,7510,5555,5556,5557,5558; undefined=14",
        "Host":"www.1ropani.com",
        "Referer":"http://www.1ropani.com/House.aspx",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1",
        "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"}
        yield FormRequest(url=url,method='POST',headers=head,formdata=payload, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        properties= response.xpath('//div[@class="search_result"]/descendant::div[@class="search_result_list"]')
        for property in properties:
            link=property.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first()
            url=response.urljoin(link)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_property, meta={'URL':url},dont_filter=False)

    def parse_property(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=NPMItem(), response=response)
        URL=response.meta.get('URL')
        l.add_value('URL',response.url)
        yield l.load_item()
'''
```

Comment: From the first sight: try to replace `method='GET'` with `method='POST'`, which is on the website originally.

Comment: @vezunchik I have tried with POST .I have tried with GET .The first page loads with a GET request and the pagination loads with XHR  POST request.

Comment: Does that mean this is solved?

Comment: No it's not solved.